# Scrollbars in HTML section don't cover the entire height

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

In my HTML pagel, the "left-section"'s scrollbar does not cover its entire height. It only shows when the window is made small enogh to cover "Link 18". At that point, the scrollbar shows up, but does not scroll beyond "Link 18" (in fact shows only half of it).

The problem goes away if I remove the code within the `<header>` tags. I.e., the scorllbar covers the entire height of the column.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Two Columns with Independent Scrollbars</title>
    <style>
        /* Styles for the container */
        .container {
            display: flex;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        /* Styles for the left section */
        .left-section {
            width: 30%;
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
            overflow-y: auto; /* Add a vertical scrollbar to the left section */
        }

        /* Styles for the right section */
        .right-section {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: #e0e0e0;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }

        /* Style for links */
        .left-section a {
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: blue;
        }

        /* Hide the main page scrollbar */
        body {
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>


    
<body>
   <header>
        <h1>Welcome to My Web Page Welcome to My Web Page Welcome to My Web Page Welcome to My Web Page </h1>
        <p>This is the banner section of the page.</p>
    </header>
    
    
    <!-- Banner Section -->

    <!-- Container for both sections -->
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Left Section with Independent Scrollbar -->
        <div class="left-section">
            <h3>Links</h3>
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            <a href="#">Link 4</a>
            <a href="#">Link 5</a>
            <a href="#">Link 6</a>
            <a href="#">Link 7</a>
            <a href="#">Link 8</a>
            <a href="#">Link 9</a>
            <a href="#">Link 10</a>
            <a href="#">Link 11</a>
            <a href="#">Link 12</a>
            <a href="#">Link 13</a>
            <a href="#">Link 14</a>
            <a href="#">Link 15</a>
            <a href="#">Link 16</a>
            <a href="#">Link 17</a>
            <a href="#">Link 18</a>
            <a href="#">Link 19</a>
            <a href="#">Link 20</a>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Right Section with Independent Scrollbar -->
        <div class="right-section">
            <!-- Content for the right section goes here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Since you want both left and right sections to be scrollable, that means that `html, body` need to be set to `100dvh` (dynamic viewport height)
- `body` also needs to be `display: flex;` set to direction `column` (and does not necessarily need to be set to `overflow: hidden` but does not hurts)
- Use `padding` instead of margin for your anchors. One plus is that the tap area is larger
- Make use of `flex` property shorthand to expand an element to the available space
- `.container` also needs to have `overflow` other than visible

```css
/* QuickReset */ * { margin: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

html, body {
  height: 100dvh;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden; /* not necessarily needed */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left-section {
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow: auto; 
  height: 100%;

  & a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
  }

}
.right-section {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <p>This is the banner section of the page.</p>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-section">
    <h3>Links</h3>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    <a href="#">Link 5</a>
    <a href="#">Link 6</a>
    <a href="#">Link 7</a>
    <a href="#">Link 8</a>
    <a href="#">Link 9</a>
    <a href="#">Link 10</a>
    <a href="#">Link 11</a>
    <a href="#">Link 12</a>
    <a href="#">Link 13</a>
    <a href="#">Link 14</a>
    <a href="#">Link 15</a>
    <a href="#">Link 16</a>
    <a href="#">Link 17</a>
    <a href="#">Link 18</a>
    <a href="#">Link 19</a>
    <a href="#">Link 20</a>
  </div>
  <div class="right-section">
    <p style="height: 200vh;">Some test paragraph really tall...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer. I had to subtract the height of the  from the bottom divs.

height: calc(100vh - 80px);

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the `height` for `.left-section`. like `76vh` or using 'px'.

```
.left-section {
    width: 30%;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 76vh;
}
```